# How do we approach this variant of Gaussian Elimination problem

Tags: algorithms

Consider a set of $N$ vectors (each of Length $L$) with positive integer as elements. Given a target vector $T$ of length $L$.

Objective: Using the given set of vectors (by addition or subtraction) reduce $T$ to the form $T'$ such that:

1. all entries in $T'$ are either 0 or 1.
2. the first entry of $T'$ is 0.

How do we approach this problem? I think it can be solved by something similar to Gaussian Elimination but I am not so sure. Can someone please comment.

Comment: What are typical values of $N$? What is the range of the integers making up the elements of the vectors? Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but currently I do not see how a solution that satisfies condition #1 is even guaranteed to exist, especially when $N$ is small and the range of integers used for the elements is large.

Comment: @njuffa there are no typical values for range of integers. We can assume that with the problem instance we are provided another input ($BitCt$) that informs about the maximum size limit entry. For simplicity sake we assume $N$ and $L$ are bounded by some polynomial relation/factor of each other. Of course a solution may or may not exist. So we can propose an algorithm that is guaranteed to work if a solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether we can use each vector more than once, we can always restrict the solutions of an arbitrary instance to those that use each vector at most once and perform only subtractions.

Indeed, we can append $N$ additional entries $x_1, \dots, x_N$ to each vector. The generic $i$-th input vector has all these entries set to $0$ except for $x_i$, which is set to $1$. The target vector has all these entries set to $1$.

Then it is possible to reduce the [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem to this version of your problem: index the items in the exact cover instances with the integers from $1$ to $N$ and create a vector $v_S$ for each set $S$. Set the $i$-th entry of $v_S$ to $2$ if item $i$ is in $S$ and to $0$ otherwise. All entries in the target vector are set to $2$.

There is a solution to your problem if and only if there is an exact cover. This shows that your problem is NP-hard.

If repetitions are allowed it is easy to design a $O^*(2^L)$-time algorithm:   guess the final values of the entries of of $T'$ (i.e., either $0$ or $1$)  and solve a system of linear Diophantine equations.

If repetitions are not allowed the trivial exhaustive algorithm runs in time $O^*(2^{2N})$. However, if $L<N$ you can design a $O^*(2^{N+L})$ algorithm by guessing $T'$ and using the "split and list" technique.

Comment: aha! I thought the problem was simple enough as it was similar to Gaussian Elimination. thank you. P.S. the enemy of all potential solutions - NPC.